# Where can I find the e-ticket number of a previously flown Turkish Airlines flight?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, airlines, turkish-airlines

I have the reservation number, but I need the 13 digit e-ticket number for a couple of months old flight with Turkish Airlines. I've done the check in online, if I remember correctly.

It seems on the airline website you can only query current bookings.

Is there a way I can find the e-ticket number for my past flight?

Comment: Not sure if checkmytrip will go back that far, but try putting PNR and surname into https://classic.checkmytrip.com

Comment: Did you check your emails ? The booking confirmation emails do mention it.

Comment: @Berwyn checkmytrip does not find it

Comment: @DumbCoder The booking was done through an agency and the booking confimation I've got does not make a reference to it.

Comment: If you can't find it in email, I suggest you call the airline then

Comment: And in addition to the suggestion of calling the airline, you might also want to call the agency that made the booking for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the e-ticket number under Ticket / Bilet No in your email confirmation. Another way call them them and ask to pull up your e-ticket number using Booking reservation code.

For example:

```
Yolcu İsmi / Passenger Name :   xx MR  
Bilet No / Ticket Number    :   2352172966699 
Rezervasyon No / Booking Ref.   :   SF7ATL
Adres / Address :   xxxx
Firma İsmi / Company Name   :   xxx
Vergi Dairesi / Hesap No    :   23457702
T.C. Kimlik Numarası    :   0
Kısıtlama / Endorsmen/Restr.    :   HUF117400 NON-REF. 
Ödeme / Payment :   TKT/CC
Esas ücret / Base Fare  :   INR 28000
Vergi / Tax :   18000CP 5000DU 100F2 2000JN 
Toplam / Total  :   HUF 60400A
Den/A   Taşıyıcı    Uçuş    Snf.    Tarih   Saat    Ücret Esası Bagaj   Bilet Durumu    Kupon Durumu    Önce Geçerli    Sonra Değil
From/To Carrier Flght   Cls Date    Time    Fare Basis  Bag Tkt St  Cpn St  Nvb Nva
BUDAPEST/BUD

ISTANBUL/IST    TK  1034    Q   08JUN   1350
1655    QF  30  OK  OPEN    08JUN   08JUN
*ISTANBUL/IST

MUMBAI/BOM  TK  0720    Q   08JUN   1950
0440    QF
```

or it is mentioned below under your name in this e-confirmation.

[image]